# skip a parameter inside function if not provided

Tags: r, if-statement, cbind

I have created a function to reshape (pivot) data, but the last part of the function is to `cbind` several columns into the df.

```
pivot_df <-  function(df, new_col, col1, col2, col3) {
     df_col_selected <- df[ , c(col1, col2, col3)]
     df_col_selected_reshaped <- reshape(
       df_col_selected, 
       idvar = col2, 
       timevar = col3,
       direction = "wide"
    )
     df_reshaped <-cbind(df_col_selected_reshaped, new_col, col1)
}
```

So if I call the function and give the names of the columns, it gives me desired outcome.

```
pivot_df(df, new_col, col1, col2, col3)
```

But I want to have a flag or `ifelse` inside this function for `new_col`. I mean `new_col` will be skipped in the last `cbind` if it is not written in the function, like this:

```
pivot_df(df, col1, col2, col3)
```

This still performs the `df_reshaped <-cbind (df_col_selected_reshaped, new_col, col1)` but there will be no `new_col` at the end.

I know I can create a separate function without `new_col` there, but I want to have a single function that can do both. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `new_col` to `NULL` as default:

```
pivot_df <-  function(df, new_col = NULL, col1, col2, col3) {
    df_col_selected <- df[ , c(col1, col2, col3)]
    df_col_selected_reshaped <- reshape(
        df_col_selected, 
        idvar = col2, 
        timevar = col3,
        direction = "wide"
    )
    if(!is.null(new_col)){
        df_reshaped <-cbind(df_col_selected_reshaped, new_col, col1)
    }else{
        df_reshaped <-cbind(df_col_selected_reshaped, col1)
    }
}
```